# Span and linear dependence of matrices of different dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have two matrices that correspond to reduced row echelon form:

$A=[I_{m-1},-x]$
and $B=[I_{m-2},-x_1,-x_2]$

with dimension $m-1\times m$  and $m-2\times m$ respectively, $x=m\times 1$ and $x_1=m-1\times 1$ and $x_2=m-1\times 1$.

Both matrices have nullspace $x$, i.e. $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$.

Is there anything I can say about the span of specifically the second matrix in relation to the first? Is it true that $A$ spans $B$? I think the elements of $x_1$ and $x_2$ should be linear combinations of $x$, but it is not clear to me how to argue so.

Comment: What does a linear combination of two matrices of different dimensions even mean?

Comment: The column dimensions of the matrices A and B are the same (m); the x, x_1 and x_2 are vectors, which the latter two have dimension one less than the former. This is an underidentification problem, I realise that, I just wonder what I can say about the span, especially if we imagine similarly defined matrices C and D with each one row less than the former.